# SonarQube RTC jazz plugin failing

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, sonarqube-msbuild-runner, ibm-jazz

I am working in a .NET environment.  I am currently using Jenkins to kick off my automated builds, SCM is Rational Team Concert.  I am using SonarQube with the MSBuild Scanner, and the ["SonarQube Jazz RTC SCM Plugin"](https://github.com/SonarQubeCommunity/sonar-scm-jazzrtc) to retrieve blame info (annotate in Rational).  Most of the time this works perfectly.  Sporadically I was seeing failures with no specific details of why the call was failing.  If I resubmited the same jenkins job the run would succeed and I would get my scans through, including all my blame info.  Recently in one of my jobs the failures started happening every time, and on the exact same file every time.  This is the stack that I get out of the jenkins console log.

```
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
INFO: Total time: 3:16.401s
ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
INFO: Final Memory: 47M/138M
INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The jazz annotate command [cmd /C call lscm annotate -u _serviceAccount -P somePassword Areas/SomeArea/Scripts/SomeFile.js] failed: 
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.jazzrtc.JazzRtcBlameCommand.blame(JazzRtcBlameCommand.java:74)
    at org.sonar.plugins.scm.jazzrtc.JazzRtcBlameCommand.blame(JazzRtcBlameCommand.java:58)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scm.ScmSensor.execute(ScmSensor.java:86)
    at org.sonar.scanner.sensor.SensorWrapper.analyse(SensorWrapper.java:53)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:57)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:49)
    at org.sonar.scanner.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:78)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:184)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.scanner.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.scanner.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.scanner.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:115)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:118)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy0.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.runAnalysis(Main.java:110)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.execute(Main.java:74)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.cli.Main.main(Main.java:61)
ERROR: 
ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
The SonarQube Scanner did not complete successfully
```

I have set the -X switch like its asking for and I do not get any more detailed info.  I have also tried setting the trace setting in the sonar.log.level to trace in the SonarQube.Analysis.xml file and I can not seem to get any more details about my failure.  There is nothing special that I can see about the file that it is failing on.  Its JavaScript, its ~1700 lines long.  It was getting the annotate/blame calls successfully up until a couple days ago.

Anyone have this issue?  Anyone know what I can do to get more details about my failure?  Any help is appreciated.

> Version info:     SonarQube 6.0   SonarQube Jazz Plugin 1.1   Rational
>   6.0.3 iFix005

**Update 1: 8/29**
     After 11 failed runs, I finally got it to go through without any errors.  This is how it looked.
      - Run1 failed on FileA
      - Run2 failed on FileA
      - Run3 failed on FileA
      - Run4 failed on FileA
      - Run5 failed on FileA
      - Run6 failed on FileA
      - Run7 failed on FileA
      - Run8 aborted
      - Run9 failed on FileB
      - Run10 failed on FileB
      - Run11 failed on FileB
      - Run12 successful on all files.

This problem is not gone, but just back to random failures.

Comment: Is it possible to split the file in parts and run the analysis again?

Comment: @JeroenHeier I think it's possible but it would require some effort. Is you thought about the size or isolating the failure to a part of the file? We have successful calls to files much larger than this one.

Comment: What happens when you run the annotate command on that file manually?

Comment: Annotate works when called from lscm on its own and it works when called from Visual Studio.

Comment: Any other thoughts?  Failing multiple times a day now.